# Redirect to front page wordpress if not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, redirect, authentication

I'm looking to redirect a user to a specific page if they are not logged in.
So blog.com/welcome

So they can either be viewing this page or wordpress login pages.
I was trying to modify this plugin 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-to-login-if-not-logged-in/

```
add_action( 'wp', 'dmk_not_loggedin_redirect' );

function dmk_not_loggedin_redirect() {
    global $pagenow;
```

However I am ending up with redirect loops. And I could use some help to stop this.

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php' or 'http://www.blog.co.uk/front' )
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.blog.co.uk/front' , 302 ); exit; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the action hook **`init`** but the current post/page information is not available yet. But then, **`template_redirect`** does the job and it only acts on the front-end, login and admin pages work normally.

Here, there's a page with the slug `welcome`, to check for a post use `is_single('post-slug')`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_so_18688269' );

function redirect_so_18688269() 
{
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( 'welcome' ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( site_url( 'welcome' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: So it compiled fine but when I tested it I got the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function uk()" However the only part that is uk is the lower level domain. So I am unsure why I got that.

The line in question was 
        ' wp_redirect( suo.blog.co.uk ( 'front' ) ); '

(not actual address)

Comment: See how it works: [Function_Reference/wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect).

Comment: I did and I am still confused. 
For example it shows using the full url. I am unsure if I should use the full URL or a partial. 
The partial works but I get the error on the page in the last post Where as using the full url which I type as `wp_redirect(http://www.example.com/ ('front') ); exit()` I get
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'
What really concerning is that the colon is only used for the URL. So I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `('front')` is to be used within `site_url()`, not as an addendum to an absolute URL. One or another.